# When user clicks on return button from home screen, it should take user back to Android "desktop"

Tags: android

When user click on back button of android device from the login screen then it should go to android desktop and our app will be exit.

how can I do this.

Plz help me.

Thank you.

Comment: when I click on my device's back button then it will come on again lo gin page..as i have written finish().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite simple. Add the following method to your `Activity`:

```
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        moveTaskToBack(true);
    }
```

Then it should just exit you app and land on the home screen.

Answer (score 0):

if login display is the `LAUNCHER` activity for your app. Then you don't need to do any code for the back button, the automatic behavior of the back button will take you out of the app and exit the app. and if you want something else on back button try to override void onBackPressed() defined in android.app.Activity class.

there is one more elegant way you can use, put the following code in your activity:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        .setTitle("Really Exit?")
        .setMessage("Are you sure you want to exit?")
        .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, null)
        .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                YourActivity.super.onBackPressed();
            }
        }).create().show();
}
```

replace `YourActivity` with your actual activity.

Comment: yaa!!no it is not my launcher activity.actually my first activity is background.for this only I call a websevice and fill all the data into my data base.this login activity is my third activity for user it is first activity.